# How can I change myLable1.Text by calling it as a variable

Tags: c#, label

Let me preface this by saying I have only been learning c# a few days. I have no prior programming experience other than basic JavaScript so I'm still unsure on a lot the correct terminology. On to the question...

Let's say I have 10 labels; myLabel1, myLabel2, myLabel3 etc and I have a variable called i.

So how can I change the .Text of myLabel by switching out the end number for the variable i? I tried making a new string:

```
string labelNumber = "myLable" + Convert.ToString(i);
```

and then:

```
lableNumber.Text = "some text";
```

Clearly this doesn't work because .Text is not a known method on lableNumber.

Comment: A string is not a Label. You can't use a string like it was a label.

Comment: You need to get access to you controls? You could hold a List or a Dictionary of them.

Comment: Which technology is this - asp.net WebForms, Windows Forms...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# as most other compiled languages will not let you do that as easily as many scripting languages.

If you want to access your controls by a string you need to collect them in a `Dictionay<string, Control>` or, if you only care about `Labels`, a `Dictionay<string, Label>` :

```
Dictionary<string, Label> labels = new Dictionary<string, Label>();

// you can do this in a loop over i:
Label newLabel = new Label();
newLabel.Name = "myLabel" + Convert.ToString(i);

// maybe set more properties..
labels.Add(newLabel.Name, newLabel );     // <-- here you need the real Label, though!
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newLabel )  // <-- or wherever you want to put them
```

Now you can access each by its name as string:

```
labels["myLabel3"].Text = "hi there";
```

Note that to add them to the `Dictionary`, (or a `List<T>` if you are happy with accessing them by an index,) you need to do it when you create them in a loop as you can't access them later; at least not without [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which imo is overkill for the situation..

**Also note** the difference between the variable name which not a string but a **token for the compiler** and its `Name` **property**, which **is** a string but **not** meant to identify the variable as it need not be **unique** and can be **changed** at any time..

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
// Create N label xontrols
Labels[] labels = new Labels[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    labels[i] = new Label();
    // Here you can modify the value of the label which is at labels[i]
}

// ...

labels[2] .Text = "some text";
```